# Overriding property attributes

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes

I have a base class with a field:

```
class Base
{
    public int A;
    public int ShowA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(A);
    }
}
```

I have a derived class:

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
    {
        A = 5;
    }
}
```

I use a GUI editor that shows all fields for a class. Because `Derived` sets `A` in its constructor I don't want it to show in the editor. The editor doesn't fields the have `[HideInInspector()]` attribute.
How can I make `Derived` have its `A` property with `[HideInInspector()]` attributes while `Base` won't?
I can't use keyword `new` because I want the `Base` still to use the same field as `Derived` in its functions (e.g. `(new Derived()).ShowA()` will print `5`).

Edit: It looks tricks with properties and `new` won't work because the GUI editor treats fields with `new` twice (once for base, and once for derived).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
class Base
{
    public virtual int A {get; set;}
    public int ShowA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(A);
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
    {
        A = 5;
    }

    [HideInInspector()]
    public override int A
    {
        get { return base.A;}
        set { base.A = value}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I please ask you what the `HideInInspector()` does ?

Comment: @Uw Concept as I said in the question, the GUI editor wont show fields with `HideInInspector()` (its not Visual Studio).

Comment: @Jon this actually works, I said I can't use it because it will separate the values, but here it won't.

Comment: Actually this won't work... the GUI editor is smart enough to include properties with `new` twice (base and derived) which doesn't show the derived but still shows base.

Comment: @Dani: I see, my mistake. Gave +1 :)

Comment: @Dani: try then make A virtual, and override it in Derived